# how to pass value from jquery to Strut2 Action class

Tags: jquery, struts2

I have created one select box after selecting any value from select box I am calling jquery function which have selected value, this value I need to pass to my Action class, I don't want to use select tag As I need to learn jquery with struts2.

Comment: So, what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this; just an example:

```
window.open('http://localhost:8080/PMBM/userdataedit.action?' + sel_id + '&operation=Edit', '_self');
```

You can use `.load()` method according to your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <script>
function callMe() {
    $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "test.action", //this action is fired
        data : {fname='rohit'} //you can pass variable 'fname' with value 'rohit'
                }).done(function(data) {

                   //Ajax response is recevied in "data"
                   //you can put other process on "data"            

                 } 


    });
}
```